# Marker Interfaces: Runtime vs compile time errors

Tags: java, interface, compilation, runtime

So reading upon the marker interface concept in Java, it kind of does not feel right to me, mostly because I am involved in writing applications where it is a disaster for the program to experience run time errors.

In terms of design when I can avoid a run time error by using for example a abstract class why would I use a marker interface where I have a risk of run time errors.

I have always thought that I will avoid  run time errors even though I may restrict the code by producing compile time errors.

Wouldn't marker interfaces cause higher risk of failures especially when more and more developers won't really read every line of documentation there is(Not me, I am one of the good guys)

Maybe its just the C++ in my head talking, but are there any advantages of designing it this way?

Comment: Well, no one likes programs which fail at runtime; I don't understand what your point is exactly? Note that you can have `@Documented` annotations if that can help you

Comment: In my opinion, marker interfaces should be regarded as deprecated, for most uses annotations are better.

Comment: @fge, with marker interfaces you are not forcing any compile time restrictions hence may cause higher chance of run time errors. So why exactly should I use it.

Comment: Certainly you can enforce that. You can require in your API that the market interface be imlemwnte, and a compile error will fault if it isn't. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJB, lets take the example of Cloneable as the marker interface. In this case, there is no restriction on the implementor to actually provide the clone function. Where if i had implemented a pure virtual function using an abstract class i would have caught it in the compilation process

Comment: @EJB why does not my question not make sense?

Comment: Because you've only managed to produce one example where it does mKe sense, and that was pre-designed. Design your own, you have enough freedom to allow for compile-time enforcement. You haven't shown otherwise.

Comment: @EJB, Hmm. So how can you enforce compile-time rules from an empty interface?

Answer (score 0):

Marker Interfaces were the only way to declare metadata about a class in early versions of Java e.g [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) says the implementing class will behave correctly when serialize/deserialize will be called.

Today Marker interfaces feel to me a bit redundant (or outdated) as they can be replaced by [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) that allow to describe class metadata in a very flexible way.

Just found a [quote](http://books.google.se/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=Joshua%20Bloch%20Marker%20Interfaces&source=bl&ots=yZEiQgr1V1&sig=tll5Od5mratwSTtjkJu46972pT0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cNbdVLfmGY7XPJ2SgOAB&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Joshua%20Bloch%20Marker%20Interfaces&f=false) from Joshua Bloch...

> You may hear it said that marker annotations (Item 35) make marker interfaces obsolete. This assertion is incorrect. Marker interfaces have two advantages over marker annotations. First and foremost, marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by instances of the marked class; marker annotations do not. The existence of this type allows you to catch errors at compile time that you couldn’t catch until runtime if you used a marker annotation.